Is security at the airport connected with immigration exit point in Ukraine?
This might be a stupid question but I’m curious if the airport security has anything to do with checking your immigration status in Ukraine?
Meaning, I’m dual citizen of Ukraine and USA. Ukraine doesn’t seem to like its citizens possessing any other passports, so I wonder if me showing my US passport that my ticket would be booked for, to the airport security in Ukraine upon exit will cause questions, or they at the airport security don’t care?
Will immigration exit point later know I have US passport?
Actually, where is the immigration exit point in the airport located?
P.S. this scenario is for airports, but obviously the Airport is closed in Ukraine right now. I’m asking for future, so I know what to do when I can fly from Ukraine again.

To be clear, you are asking about the airport security in Ukraine (e.g. at Kyiv airport)? TSA is usually a specific American term referring to the Transportation Security Agency of the United States government, the agency responsible for airport security screening in the United States.

How things work can vary quite a bit depending on the country (and even possibly on the specific airport). You'll need to be more specific.

Given that Ukraine doesn’t recognise dual nationality, it seems unwise to post on TSE or elsewhere under what looks like your real name…

xngtng, Yes, I am sorry, I realize the TSA is USA agency only. I am referring to something similar Ukraine would have in their airport. There's check in with the airline, and nex is Security. My question was if that Security person is connected to the airline check-in and to the Exit Immigration point. Or they only want to check if my ticket matches my passport and I don't carry forbidden items.  But thanks for the answer - I appreciate it.

No worries, I have edited the question to make it in the title that it is for Ukraine.

When leaving the Ukraine your documents will be checked at least three times:

During check-in, the airline will verify that you have the required documents to enter the US. Since you are a US citizen, you MUST provide your US passport. The airlines will provide a passenger manifest to the US. They may also provide a passenger manifest to Ukraine (hard to know). Given the difficult situation that Ukraine is currently in, there is a good chance they want to know who is entering and leaving the country.
You will have to show your passport and boarding pass when entering security. Here they will just check if name on ID and boarding pass are the same. Typically boarding passes do not show citizenship, so you can use either one here.
At exit immigration you need to show your Ukrainian passport. It's possible that they have access to the passenger manifest and they may cross check, in which case you'd be busted. You could try your US passport, but it's very possible that they run your name through their data systems especially if your name, language and appearance suggest you are Ukrainian.

You need to be careful here. Some Ukrainians are currently not permitted to leave the country, so chances are they are going to check departing passengers  pretty thoroughly. Some paths you can take here are potentially illegal and may have serious consequences if you get caught.
The standard solution for travelers who want to keep their dual citizenship hidden is to book two separate tickets through a "neutral" country.

thank you for your answer - it is helpful. My US and Ukrainian passports are to two different names - maiden and US on married. In this case,  if I fly from Ukraine, I check in with Ukrainian passport, Correct? and then which passport I show at security? US or Urkainian? If I show US passport that will at least match my name on the ticket. If I show Ukrainian passport, will they have a problem at security that my ticket doesn't match my Ukrainian passport? And then at exit immigration as I show Ukrainian passport, will they see that it is not the same one I checked into the airline?

@TanyaKryvoruchenko you won't be able to check in for a flight to the US with your Ukrainian passport because it does not have a valid US visa in it.

"I check in with Ukrainian passport, Correct?" No. As I clearly stated in my answer: at check-in  " you MUST provide your US passport." Passport at security must match name on ticket. Passport at Ukraine exit should be Ukrainian but the may also look at your boarding pass. If that's in a different name, you have a problem.

Could you please clarify what does it mean passengers manifest? As in “The airlines will provide a passenger manifest to the US. They may also provide a passenger manifest to Ukraine (hard to know)“

The airlines always create a passenger manifest. That's a list of all people who have boarded the plane and some information about them (often including passport info).  In some cases the airline is required to share some or all of this data with the arrival country (that's what the APIS system is). They may share this also this with the departing country depending on what laws are applicable and what agreements are in place.

In short: unrelated, but...
The documents you use to exit a country is independent to the documents you specify in ticket (or just the name in the ticket), for API (advanced passenger information) and such things.
But at exit, officers may verify that your ticket is linked to you: the exit check is also for illegal human trade, smuggling, etc. so officers may have further checks if documents are suspicious. On usual case, a second passport may be shown, which it is just used for identity and ticket verification.
From your question, can I assume it is illegal to have dual citizenship for Ukrainian? If it is not the case, they may not like it, but you can do it. In the second case, you are already outside law, so... things are already complex. I think a safer way it is to book a connecting flight, where you can enter with your Ukrainian passport, and where you can link the ticket with it.

For many countries with exit check, for example India, immigration agents will check if you have a visa to enter the country you are traveling to. If they can't find a US visa in Ukranian passport, then game over.

Are you sure it is immigration agents? Usually airlines, because they get fines if they transport people e.g. in US without visas or other authorization. But exit agent has not knowledge on visa requirements on all countries (and for US... there are green cards, etc.) -- note: sometime security will check for suspicious travels and ask you for details, but that is about foreign fighters, etc. E.g. if you exit Israel (but not from there), but there is no check on entry visas, just if you can be a danger on an aircraft.

Often immigration agents check visas even though in most countries they don't.  It seems more common in those countries where dual nationality is discouraged or forbidden.

So the layover option is the best

Giacomo, Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. I don't know if it is illegal to have dual citizenship. I don't think it is illegal, I think it just unrecognized. I've heard different stories - that it is simply not welcomed and Ukrainian passport is demanded. US embassy in Ukraine told me that they have instances of those who tried to get in/out of Ukraine on US passports only, got their US passports confiscated. But there are some people who get in and out on other passports with not problem. So I am not totally sure what the actual law is...

yes, sounds like layover is best option. But when yo usay layover, you mean I need to purchase a totally separate ticket onto my name in Ukainian passport and then another one on my US passport? Or jsut have a connecting flight with a layover?

@TanyaKryvoruchenko the US doesn't much care about dual citizenship.  The problem is that Ukraine doesn't permit it.  Wikipedia says that Ukraine rarely undertakes the process of revoking Ukrainian citizenship of those who have naturalized elsewhere because it is long and expensive.  I do not know.  But it would be odd for Ukrainian authorities to confiscate US passports, so I think there may be some misunderstanding.

@TanyaKryvoruchenko Current Ukrainian law does not recognise dual nationality.  Local authorities will treat dual nationals entering the country on Ukrainian passports as Ukrainian. However it seems that is likely to change through a bill on multiple citizenship and other related changes

thanks so much, understood. So as long as I have valid Ukranian passport they won't detain/fine me for having USA passport as well, hopefully;:)

Note: in general one should not use a passport of an other country when exiting own country (and the same entering). That rule is pretty general
